# Handling redirects on User Validation in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm wondering how others manage return visitors who are already logged into their site (Proved with cookie token)

Currently, I'm using a redux action in the root component, which triggers an API call to check if the cookie is valid or not.

When this comes back as `TRUE` of `FALSE` the next action is dependant on the URL that a user is trying to visit.

**Currently:**
- If a user is validated and visits `/` they will be sent to /contacts

- If a user is **not** validated and they visit any protected route (e.g. `/contacts`) the will be kicked out to `/`.

**Issues:**
- A validated user will momentarily see the login page if they visit `/` before being forwarded. 
- If they visit another protect route such as `/form` they will be kicked over to `/contacts`

I know that both these items are a result of being temporarily not logged in while the API call validates the user.

**Question**
I'm wondering how you handle this in your application?
1. Avoid seeing the login page while validation is happening if user is logged in.
2. If user is logged in get them to the page they've requested?

// App.js Router

```
class App extends Component {
    componentWillMount = async () => {
        await this.props.checkLogin();
    }

    render() {
        const { loggedIn } = this.props;
        const myProtectedRoutes = [
            {component: Form, path: "/form", exact: true },
            {component: Contacts, path: "/contacts", exact: true },
            {component: ContactCard, path: "/contacts/card/:clientID", exact: true },
        ]
        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename="/" >
                <div>
                    <NavBar isLoggedIn={loggedIn} />
                    <main>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
                            <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout   }/>
                            {myProtectedRoutes.map( 
                                (d, i) => 
                                <ProtectedRoute
                                    key={i}
                                    isAccessible={ loggedIn ? true : false }
                                    exact
                                    redirectToPath={"/"}
                                    path={d.path}
                                    component={d.component}
                                    />
                            )}
                        </Switch>
                    </main>
                    <footer>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" component={Footer}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

// LoginForm.js component => appears at '/'

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            emailaddress:   '',
            password:       '',
        }
    }
    onLoginSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { emailaddress, password } = this.state;

        if (emailaddress && password) {
            this.props.doLogin(emailaddress, password, stayloggedin);
        }
    }
    render() {
        let { loggedIn } = this.props

        // If logged in is true go to contacts or
        // I'd like to be able to get to the typed 
        // URL if logged in is true.
        if ( loggedIn ){
            return <Redirect push to={"/contacts"} />
        }
        return (
            <div id="mainloginform" className="container">
                <!-- Login form Fields go here -->
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us with your code so we can look into your issue in particular?

Comment: I've added in the `Router` and the `Redirect` code.

Comment: https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/tree/master/login-react

Answer (score 0):

In general, user validation and redirects should happen in the server.

In [express](https://expressjs.com/), when the user requests any route (`/` or `/contacts`), following things should happen

- Check if the user is valid(using cookie token)
- If valid, redirect the user to the requested route.
- If invalid, redirect the user to `/`(using `req.redirect('/')`)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! How does this work in the case of a react app? Where server and application are kind of treated as separate entities. Thus the React App must request to be validated when it loads?

Answer (score 0):

In redux it is a common pattern to make three actions.
Consider showing a "in_progress" UI during fetch?

```
{ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' }
{ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE', error: 'Oops' }
{ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', response: { ... } }
```

Refer [here](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions) for more details.